# The return type 'Future<Null>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dynamic, future

Help  The return type 'Future' isn't a 'Widget',

```
Future deleteProduct(String productId) async {
    String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products' + productId;
    var response = await http.delete(Uri.parse(url));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Code structure

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: const Text('Data berhasil Dihapus'));
        Navigator.push( context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>deleteProduct((snapshot.dataas dynamic)['data'][index]['id'].toString()).then((value) {setState(() {});
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) .showSnackBar( snackBar);
    })));
```

Need Help Thanks.

Error `"The return type 'Future<Null>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Future` function to include `return type` of `Map<String, dynamic>`

```
Future<Map<String,dynamic> deleteProduct(String productId) async {
    String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products' + productId;
    var response = await http.delete(Uri.parse(url));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

And use `FutureBuilder` in the `builder` like:

```
    GestureDetector(
       onTap: () async {
         Navigator.push( context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => FutureBuilder(
                                   future: deleteProduct((snapshot.dataas dynamic)['data'][index]['id'].toString()),
                                   builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                                     if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                                       if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                         return Center(
                                            child: Text('${snapshot.error} occurred',
                                           ),
                                         );
                                       }
                                     } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                        final data = snapshot.data as String;
                                        return Center(
                                           child: Text('$data'),
                                        );
                                     }   

                                   return CircularProgressIndicator();                                  
                                 }
         
           )));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use your **future** `Function` in `onTap` and then use **`showSnackbar`**.

**Example.**

```
    GestureDetector(
       onTap: () async {
         await deleteProduct((snapshot.dataas dynamic)['data'][index]['id'].toString()).then((){
         final snackBar = SnackBar(
                         content: const Text('Data berhasil Dihapus'));
       Navigator.push( context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>deleteProduct((snapshot.dataas dynamic)['data'][index]['id'].toString()).then((value) {setState(() {});
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) .showSnackBar( snackBar);
        })));
});
```

Comment: Did you check the code you suggested? At SO, we must be mindful that our answers must be validated, to save time of fellow developers.